# WooCommerce get_availability() returns an array

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, stock

I'm trying to display the availability of a product inside a function using woocommerce 3.0.8.

My code is:

```
global $product;    
echo $product->get_availability();
```

It prints the word Array and nothing else. shouldn't it work?
I can't figure out what's wrong

Comment: Please post the output of ´var_dump($product->get_availability())´. It'll help with your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:**

There is a little mistake in WooCommerce documentation as [**`WC_Product` `get_availability()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_get_availability) method return **an array** of 2 keys/values:

- The availability **text** based on stock status *(with the key `'availability'`).*
- The availability **classname** based on stock status *(with the key `'class'`)*

So you can't use echo with an array. To see that use `print_r()` like:

```
global $product;    
print_r($product->get_availability());
```

So your code will be:

```
global $product; 
$availability = $product->get_availability();
echo $availability['availability']; // the availability text
echo '<br>'; // 
echo $availability['class']; // the availability class
```

---

**Note:** It is not possible using **`WC_Product`** [`get_availability_text()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_get_availability_text) or [`get_availability_class()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_get_availability_class) methods as they are **protected** *(usable by woocommerce only)*:

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to other responses, but I use the following code to get the *availability class* because `get_availability_class()` has not worked for me in all cases:

```
$avail = $product->get_availability();
$class = $avail['class']
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help, i really appreciate it.
i have fixed it using

```
global $product;     
$availability = $product->get_availability();
return $availability[availability];
```

and it works like a charm. thanks again